# Redshift regex for before and after certain char

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Data :- 1,2,3=20,4,5

`select regexp_substr(data,',3=[^,]*')`

output =  ,3=20

Desired output = 20

How do I get rid of,3=? I can add `split_part(regexp_substr(Data,',713=[^,]*'),'=',2)` but using the same expression would make sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract a pattern using a subexpression:

```
select regexp_substr(data, ',3=([^,]*)', 1, 1, 'e')
```

Comment: @harshilbhatt . . . These are explained in the documentation:  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(Data, ',3=([0-9.]+)', 1, 1, 'e')
```

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/ynxWrR/1/)

**Details**

- `,3=` - a literal string
- `([0-9.]+)` - Capturing group 1 (aka *subexpression*, see below explanations): one or more digits or dots.

The [`REGEXP_SUBSTR` docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html) explain the options:

- `1` is the *position* argument and it sets the *"position within source_string to begin searching"*.
- `1` is the *occurrence* argument that means we want to extract the first occurrence of the pattern.
- `'e'` is the *parameters* argument and means we want to *"extract a substring using a subexpression"*, i.e. the contents captured with a [**capturing group**](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). *"If pattern includes a subexpression, `REGEXP_SUBSTR` matches a substring using the first subexpression in pattern. `REGEXP_SUBSTR` considers only the first subexpression; additional subexpressions are ignored. If the pattern doesn't have a subexpression, REGEXP_SUBSTR ignores the 'e' parameter."*